# Shadow won't update when geometry is changed using VertexShader

Tags: three.js, shader

I'm using a custom shader to curve a plane. My custom shader extends the Lambert shader so it supports lights and shadows. It all works as expected, but when the vertexShader changes the geometry of the plane, the shadow doesn't update. Is there anything I'm missing to flag that the geometry has updated in my vertexShader and the shadow needs to change?

[Here is a screenshot of the problem. The plane is curved with a vertexShader, but the shadow doesn't update][1]
     [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kfCF.png

Here is the demo/code: http://dev.cartelle.nl/curve/
If you drag the "bendAngle" slider you can see that the shadow doesn't update.

One work-around I thought was to get the bounding box of my curved plane. Then use those points and create a new Mesh/Box and use that object to cast the shadow. But then I wasn't sure how to get the coordinates of the new curved geometry. When I would check geometry.boundingBox after the shader was applied, it would also just give me the original coordinates every time.

Thanks
Johnny

Comment: Please add the relevant code snippets to your question. Links can break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are modifying the geometry positions in the vertex shader, and you are casting shadows, you need to specify a *custom depth material* so the shadows will respond to the modified positions.

In your custom depth material's vertex shader, you modify the vertex positions in the same way you modified them in the material's vertex shader.

An example of a custom depth material can be seen in [this three.js example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_animation_cloth.html), (although vertices are not modfied in the vertex shader in that example; they are modified on the CPU).

In your case, you would create a vertex shader for the custom depth material using a pattern like so:

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexShaderDepth">

  uniform float bendAngle;
  uniform vec2 bounds;
  uniform float bendOffset;
  uniform float bendAxisAngle;

    vec3 bendIt( vec3 ip, float ba, vec2 b, float o, float a ) {
        // your code here
        return ip;
    }

    void main() {

        vec3 p = bendIt( position, bendAngle, bounds, bendOffset, bendAxisAngle );

        vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( p, 1.0 );

        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;

    }

</script>
```

And fragment shader like this:

```
<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentShaderDepth">

    vec4 pack_depth( const in float depth ) {

        const vec4 bit_shift = vec4( 256.0 * 256.0 * 256.0, 256.0 * 256.0, 256.0, 1.0 );
        const vec4 bit_mask  = vec4( 0.0, 1.0 / 256.0, 1.0 / 256.0, 1.0 / 256.0 );
        vec4 res = fract( depth * bit_shift );
        res -= res.xxyz * bit_mask;
        return res;

    }

    void main() {

        gl_FragData[ 0 ] = pack_depth( gl_FragCoord.z );

    }
</script>
```

Then in your javascript, you specify the custom depth material:

```
uniforms = {};
uniforms.bendAngle = { type: "f", value: properties.bendAngle };
uniforms.bendOffset = { type: "f", value: properties.offset };
uniforms.bendAxisAngle = { type: "f", value: properties.bendAxisAngle };
uniforms.bounds = { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2( - 8, 16 ) };

var vertexShader = document.getElementById( 'vertexShaderDepth' ).textContent;
var fragmentShader = document.getElementById( 'fragmentShaderDepth' ).textContent;

myObject.customDepthMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader
} );
```

three.js r.74

Comment: So it looks like in r.84 we should assign customDepthMaterial to materials instead of meshes. I have a custom ShaderMaterial that displaces vertices, and I'm also assigning a customDepthMaterial to it. The depth material has no effect and surprisingly doesn't throw an error if I put a typo in its fragmentShader. And console.log(myMaterial.customDepthMaterial.fragmentShader) shows the desired depth fragment shader. Any guess why I can't plug in a customDepthMaterial? (I've also done myObject.castShadow =
    myObject.receiveShadow = true)